# API does not collect required data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to get route prices with Skyscanner API in JavaScript. I paste the snippet from Rapid API and put it in a function:

```
function takeData() {
    console.log("to jest test")
    fetch("https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/US/USD/en-US/SFO-sky/JFK-sky/2020-08-12?inboundpartialdate=2020-08-23", {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "x-rapidapi-host": "skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": "4ffdf62c6bmshfb49ff445025abep1e2116jsn7d7aae645a00"
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

takeData()
```

Instead of getting details as shown in Rapid API

[image]

I get this:

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.r…/JFK-sky/2020-08-12?inboundpartialdate=2020-08-23", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/US/USD/en-US/SFO-sky/JFK-sky/2020-08-12?inboundpartialdate=2020-08-23"
__proto__: Response
```

Any ideas what may be more to do here? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to parse the response body as JSON :

try this

```js
function takeData() {
    console.log("to jest test")
    fetch("https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/US/USD/en-US/SFO-sky/JFK-sky/2020-08-12?inboundpartialdate=2020-08-23", {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "x-rapidapi-host": "skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": "4ffdf62c6bmshfb49ff445025abep1e2116jsn7d7aae645a00"
        }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

takeData()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close. You just need to update your fetch call to parse the response so that it returns `json`. See the second `then` block.

```
return response.json();
```

Full code below:

```js
fetch("https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/US/USD/en-US/SFO-sky/JFK-sky/2020-08-12?inboundpartialdate=2020-08-23", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": "4ffdf62c6bmshfb49ff445025abep1e2116jsn7d7aae645a00"
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```